# Reduce the expression $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}}$ into a Geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to reduce the expression $$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}}$$ into a Geometric series.

Comment: By 'GS' did you mean Geometric series?

Comment: it could be "general solution"?

Answer (score 1):

If $$y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}},$$ then $y^2=x+y$, so $y=\frac{1±\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It is interesting that for $x\gt 0$ the answer is positive so the positive sign must be taken  - indeed $y\gt 1$ in this case. But for $x=0$ we have $y=0$ which can only be obtained by choosing the negative sign.

Comment: Yes, you are right Mark, on purpose I did not elaborate, awaiting a reaction from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

To play on the previous answer, and to show how it works, let
$$y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}$$
Then
$$y^2=x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}=x+y$$
Thus, we get $y^2-y-x=0$ and you can use the QF to solve for y

$\mathbf{EDIT}$

If you are indeed looking for the general solution, then Nicky Hester solved using the QF to get that 
$$y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$
If you are looking for integral solutions, you need to show $\sqrt{1+4x}$ is an odd integer, since $2y-1=\sqrt{1+4x}$.  Also $1+4x$ must be a square.  Thus, let $k^2=4x+1$.  Letting $x=n(n+1)$ yield $4n(n+1)+1=4n^2 +4n+1=(2n+1)^2$  Therefore $y$ is an integer solution when $x$ is the product of two consecutive numbers.